# Segmentation Fault with opening and closing Pygame WIndows

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I'm working on a project where I am trying to alternate between the camera preview on a picamera, and some text on screen using pygame windows. I have gotten to the point where I can open the picamera, then some text, then the picamera again, but when I try to open a pygame window for more text, I get a segmentation fault.

I think the main problem is quitting the pygame window, without quitting the other things I need to open up another pygame window. The commands like sys.exit, and pygame.quit seem to quit things to much. I've tried alternatives like putting the text into a while loop and then making the loop false at the end so that it closes the window without an actual quit command, but that didn't seem to close anything really. The code works perfectly up until the second time I try to initialize pygame. That's when it gives me the segmentation fault and opens a new window in my python idle with a whole bunch of other code that I didn't write.

```
pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue= (0, 0, 128)
black = (0, 0, 0)
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1350,800))
pygame.display.set_caption('   ')

camera()

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
text = font.render('You', True, black, white)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (1350//2, 800//2)
display_surface.fill(white)
display_surface.blit(text, textRect)
for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         quit()
     pygame.display.update()
     time.sleep(1)
     pygame.quit()

camera()

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue= (0, 0, 128)
black = (0, 0, 0)
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1350,800))
pygame.display.set_caption('   ')
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
text = font.render('test', True, black, white)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (1350//2, 800//2)
display_surface.fill(white) 
display_surface.blit(text, textRect)
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
         quit()
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(1)
```

What I would like to be able to do is switch between picamera and text several more times, so if I can figure out how to fix it this one time, then I just have to copy and paste the code a bit more to get the next iterations. I'm brand new to coding.

Comment: I don't understand why you repeate the same code two times. Don't you know how to use loop ? And I don't understand why you use `pygame.quit()` and later you create new window with the same size - you could use one windiw all the time.

Comment: inside `for event` you use `pygame.quit()` which can close window and stop access to events but you still run event loop. Maybe you have wrong indentations. Did you run code in console/terminal (not IDLE) to see if it display any error message except Segmentation Fault?

Comment: what is `camera()` ? What are you doing in this function? What modules do youimport ?

Comment: running in terminal still gives a segmentation fault. I'm using the same code two times because I'm hoping to open two windows with different text on them. And I use the pygame.quit after the time.sleep so that it will quit on its own after a certain amount of time.

Comment: the camera() is a function that I built earlier, I left out the actual code for that since it was working fine. It just opens the camera preview for a second and then closes itself.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. so I made a silly mistake. The problem is, for some reason, initializing pygame twice; which I still don't understand since `pygame.quit()` should have quit it I think. But I just removed the second `pygame.init()` and replaced the first `pygame.quit()` with `pygame.display.quit()` instead.