# Why does my jupyter notebook keeps crashing when rendering text in pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame, rendering, jupyter

I'm using jupyter notebook to make a py-game. I've noticed that EVERY TIME I render some text in the game, the notebook will collapse. It works when I run the game and the text is shown as expected. However, when I close the game's window and try to run the code for a second time it will collapse. Some times it will work for a couple of tries, but it'll collapse at some point. Other times, the notebook just collapses as soon as I close the game's window.

The relevant part of the code would be:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
run=True
#screensize
screensize = (width,height)=(600,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)

#font used for the text
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
#the text that will be rendered. It is usually some variable value, but the problem remains even if it is constant:
vel=3.001


while run:
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False 
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    ########rendering the text############
    textsurface = myfont.render(str(int(vel)), False, (0, 100, 100))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(200,400))
    ######################################

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Lets say I run the code and the I close the window. If I try to run the code again, the message is:

Le noyau semble planté. Il va redémarrer automatiquement.

**(the kernel appears to have died. it will restart automatically)**

I've been advised not to use pygame with jupyter notebook, but I jus't can't code outside that environment.

Comment: can't you use use text editor or IDE for this ?

Comment: I'm pretty much an amateur. Don't really know what you mean. :|

Comment: I means don't use `Jupyter` but text editor (like `Notepad++`, `Gean`, `Sublime Text`, etc.) or IDE (like `PyCharm`, `Visual Studio Code`, etc.). OR run code like any other program - without Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But migrating from jupyter notebook is just not an option for me. I have a lot to learn and changing the environment I use would be to hard at this point, as jupyter is the only one I've used since I started coding

Comment: `Jupyter` was created to work with science modules and probably nobody expected that it will be used with game module `pygame`. And `pygame` (and library SDL used by `pygame`) was created many years before first jupyter was created and nobody expected that it will used in something like Jupyter.

Comment: The only idea: few days ago someone has problem to run `pygame` window many times in game (without `Jupyter`) on Windows (on Linux it worked correctly). Solution was to use `pygame.init()` only once, never use `pygame.quit()` and use `pygame.display.init()` to before creating window again, and `pygame.display.quit()` to close window at the end.

Comment: This totally worked for me, the only disadvantage being that I must use two cells instead of only one to activate pygame just once... not complaining at all

Comment: BTW: I found mentioned question with `pygame.display.init()` - [Segmentation Fault with opening and closing Pygame WIndows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617733/segmentation-fault-with-opening-and-closing-pygame-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by user 'furas' above, activating pygame once and replacing pygame.init() for pygame.display.init(); and pygame.quit() by pygame.display.quit() solved this problem for me. Not sure if it implies more resources being used, but so far it has shown no problems in my rather basic laptop.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

In a different cell:

```
pygame.display.init()
run=True
#screensize
screensize = (width,height)=(600,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)

#font used for the text
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
#the text that will be rendered. It is usually some variable value, but the problem remains even if it is constant:
vel=3.001


while run:
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False 
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    ########rendering the text############
    textsurface = myfont.render(str(int(vel)), False, (0, 100, 100))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(200,400))
    ######################################

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.quit()
```